# Compiler Error Message: CS1061: (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'List' 
does not contain a definition for 'EmpModels' and 
no extension method 'EmpModels' accepting a first argument of type 
'List' could be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Model Class

```
public class EmpModel
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string empname { get; set; }
}
public class EmpDetails
{
public List<EmpModel> EmpModels { get; set; }
}
```

In Controller

```
public ActionResult GetAllEmployees(EmpDetails empDet)
        {
            connection();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("spEmployeeDetails", con)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            empDet.EmpModels = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows

                       select new EmpModel()
                       {
                           id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]),
                           empname = Convert.ToString(dr["empname"]),  
                       }).ToList();
            return View(empDet);
 }
```

In View

```
@model List<CDMA_SSO.Models.EmpModel>

@foreach (var item in Model.EmpModels)
{
@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.empname)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add namespace in the Model class

`System.Collections.Generic;`